# How to get the relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have three model : `Manager` ,`Vendor`, `Banquet`
and the relationship is :

- manager has one vendor
- vendor has many banquet

How to get the all manager with all relation in laravel orm?

```
$manager = Manager::where('active',1)->get();
$vendor = $manager->vendor()->get();// -- dose not work! 
$banquet =  $vendor->banquet()->get();// -- dose not work!
```

Manager model:

```
class Manager extends Model{
     protected $table = 'manager';
     protected $primaryKey = 'id';

     public function vendor(){
     return $this->hasOne('ACME\Entities\Vendor','managerId','id');
   }
}
```

Here is the model

Vendor model:

```
class Vendor extends Model{
    protected $table = 'vendor';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function manager(){
      return $this->belongsTo('ACME\Entities\Manager_V','id','managerId');
    }

    public function banquet(){
        return $this->hasMany('ACME\Entities\V_Banquet' ,'vendorId' ,'id');
    }
}
```

Banquet model:

```
class Banquet extends Model{
    protected $table = 'banquet';
    protected $primaryKey ='id';

    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ACME\Entities\Vendor' ,'vendorId' ,'id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **with** method

```
$manager =  Manager::with(['vendor','vendor.banquet'])->where('active',1)->get();
```

You will be able to get data as

```
$banquet = $manager->vendor->banquet;
// $banquet will be array of banquet model objects
```

Remember hasMany return array, hasOne return Object and belongsTo return Object.

Comment: Ok,If I need to add  a new relation codition
$vendor = $manager->vendor()->where('active',1)->get();
How can I do .

Comment: I guess you want to add a condition on relation model.

Answer (score 1):

That didn't work because `get()` gives the collection of managers. Vendor hasmany banquets so, `banquets()` in vendor model would be good convention. And You should do something like this:

```
    $managers = Manager::where('active',1)->with('vendor','vendor.banquets')->get(); 
    foreach($managers as $manager)
    {
          $vendor=$manager->vendor;
          print_r($vendor);
          foreach($vendor->banquets as $banquet)
          {
                  print_r($banquet);
          }
    }
```